# How to establish connection to SSAS Tabular Model using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssas, ssas-tabular

I am trying to establish connection to Azure SSAS using Python .Below is my python script snippet ,when I execute the Python script it error out with listed error attached below:
I checked my C drive for ADOMD client and unable to find it. 
I am using SSAS 2017. 
Can you please help to resolve the error in the screenshot ?

[image]

I am referring the Code snippet from this link :
https://github.com/yehoshuadimarsky/python-ssas

I also referred the link to understand about 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient' error

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/47d0b992-3c10-4851-b2a5-9f72d2c0976e/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftanalysisservicesadomdclient-error?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Comment: have you installed the SSAS client librarys? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-data-providers

Answer (score 1):

The Pyadomd package might help you with your problem:

[Pyadomd](https://github.com/S-C-O-U-T/Pyadomd)